# Reading groups of lines from a large text file

Tags: bash, file, text

I am looking to pull certain groups of lines from large (~870,000,000 line) text files.  For example in a 50 line file I might want lines 3-6, 18-27, and 39-45.

From browsing Stack Overflow, I have found that the bash command:

```
tail -n+NUMstart file |head -nNUMend
```

is the fastest way to get a single line or group of lines starting at NUMstart and going to NUMend.  However when reading multiple groups of lines this seems inefficient.  Normally the technique wouldn't matter so much, but with files this large it makes a huge difference.

Is there a better way to go about this than using the above command for each group of lines?  I am assuming the answer will most likely be a bash command but am really open to any language/tool that will do the job best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show lines 3-6, 18-27 and 39-45 with sed:

```
sed -n "3,6p;18,27p;39,45p" file
```

---

It is also possible to feed sed from a file.

Content of file `foobar`:

```
3,6p
18,27p
39,45p
```

Usage:

```
sed -n -f foobar file
```

Comment: I am curious if this would be much faster than `awk`.

Comment: this will scan the whole file, can't be faster than `awk` with an exit after the last line.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk -v lines='3-6,18-27,39-45' '
       BEGIN {n=split(lines,a,","); 
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                {split(a[i],t,"-"); 
                 rs[++c]=t[1]; re[c]=t[2]}} 

             {for(i=s;i<=c;i++) 
              if(NR>=rs[i] && NR<=re[i]) {print; next} 
              else if(NR>re[i]) s++; 
              if(s>c) exit}' file
```

provides an early exit after the last printed line.  No error checking, the ranges should be provided in increasing order.

Comment: Good approach. However, I don't think the range feeding is a particular problem here, so the `BEGIN` block is somehow irrelevant (to me).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `tail -n XX file | head -n YY` for different ranges is that you are running it several times, hence the inefficiency. Otherwise, [benchmarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47423/40596) suggest that they are the best solution.

For this specific case, you may want to use `awk`:

```
awk '(NR>=start1 && NR<=end1) || (NR>=start2 && NR<=end2) || ...' file
```

In your case:

```
awk '(NR>=3 && NR<=6) || (NR>=18 && NR<=27) || (NR>=39 && NR<=45)' file
```

That is, you group the ranges and let `awk` print the corresponding lines when they occur, just looping through the file once. It may be also useful to add a final `NR==endX {exit}` (`endX` being the closing item from the last range) so that it finishes processing once it has read the last interesting line.

In your case:

```
awk '(NR>=3 && NR<=6) || (NR>=18 && NR<=27) || (NR>=39 && NR<=45); NR==45 {exit}' file
```